# Routing express to ng2 without template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular

I have generated the default express application, which I modified to have the following lines in it's `app.js` file.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

in the ./views directory, I originally had `layout.jade`, `index.jade` and `error.jade`. OK, so far so good. when the project is run, I get either the index or error layout shown.

Now... I want to add a minimal angular2 installation, with a view to having ng2 manage a 1 page application where `index.jade` currently is.

So I have put an `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

in and a `main.ts` file:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Then I changed `index.jade` to `index.html` and added:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/style.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, with the html templating engine and my new `error.html` and `index.html` files, I always get shown the error page and not my ng2 managed index. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you figure this out? The suggestion below says ejs but I as well do not want to use a template engine. What is the correct way to serve an index.html file with the angular 2 selector in it. So that I can pass the front end off to angular 2 without out any weird errors. Like when I refresh the page etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best option right now is to use ejs (engine) and configure it to accept and render html.

**Code:**

app.set('views', path.join(*__dirname*, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // template engine

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); //turn engine to use html

Note: All your views or templates should .html extension